# How do I include a library in an .so file in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile a `.so` file the relies on the FTDI library. I'm not sure how to include the library so that it compiles correctly. (Below is my best guess). Is this possible or is there another way to go about it?

```
shared: pldevice pldeviceenttecpro pluniverse
    $(CC) -shared  -Wl,-soname,libplanklight.so -o libplanklight.so\
    -L/usr/local/lib -lftd2xx \
    pldevice.o pldeviceenttecpro.o pluniverse.o
```

Edit: This is what the output is:

```
g++ -fPIC -c pldevice.cpp
g++ -fPIC -c pldeviceenttecpro.cpp
g++ -fPIC -c pluniverse.cpp
g++ -shared  -Wl,-soname,libplanklight.so -o libplanklight.so\
-L/usr/local/lib -lftd2xx \
pldevice.o pldeviceenttecpro.o pluniverse.o
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot open output file   libplanklight.so-L/usr/local/lib: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'shared' failed
make: *** [shared] Error 1
```

Comment: What problems do you have? How does the command you show work or not work?

Comment: looks like you are simply missing a space before the first \

Comment: If you look at the error message, it should be quite clear what the problem is. Add a space somewhere (like before the backslash).

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a space.

```
 $(CC) -shared  -Wl,-soname,libplanklight.so -o libplanklight.so \
                                                                ^^
                                                     Add a space here
```

The \ just makes the command continue on the next line, so when you have

```
-o libplanklight.so\
-L/usr/local/lib
```

It will be the same as `-o libplanklight.so-L/usr/local/lib`

But you want `-o libplanklight.so -L/usr/local/lib`

Comment: Yep that was the issue, Thanks, I should have seen that